# Is CSS "!important" tag cross-browser?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I'm using a lot of `**!important**` in my CSS to override Twitter Bootstrap defaults. I wonder if it will work across all devices.

Does `**!important**` give me same results in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my personal experience `!important` supported by every browser that supports CSS. But you have to check [This](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) before use it.

Answer (score 1):

It was part of the `CSS` spec and has been around forever, and was always easy enough to implement that browsers appear to have gotten it right on the first try.

Here are the browser will support `!important`
IE5.5+, Firefox 1+, Safari 3+, Chrome 1+.